# What does "Ninemen" mean, in the name of the Nulathoe's Ninemen spell?

Tags: spells, lore, adnd-2e, adnd-1e, terminology

Every reference to Ed Greenwood's spell *Nulathoe's ninemen* makes sure to note that "ninemen" is pronounced "nin-em-en" rather than "nine men," making it a unique word of some sort.

I'm just curious whether this is some archaic word I've never run into, or whether any canonical source (even just Ed Greenwood's say-so) defines this term. Is there any dictionary or official source that explains the meaning of "ninemen" in this context?

Comment: For reference, the spell _Nullathoe's ninemen_ first appears in _Dragon's Bestiary_, Dragon #32 p.39 (Dec 1979), in the description of the _crawling claw_, a creature created by Greenwood; the pronunciation first appears somewhat later, in _Pages from the Mages_, Dragon #62 p.17 (June 1982). However, no definition of "ninemen" is given in any source I can find. Ed Greenwood appears to be active [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/TheEdVerse), so someone might tweet him.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the conversation speculating on the origin has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116912/discussion-on-question-by-afroakuma-nulathoes-ninemen-what-does-ninemen-mea).

Comment: What sort of answer would answer this other than a direct statement from the designer? My concern is that [asking for designer intent](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7964/52137) was made off-topic because of the answers they tended to draw, namely highly speculative/unsupported answers which weren't resolved properly. This inquiry might be better suited to a different [forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/52137) and/or twitter (as suggested above).

Comment: Reasonable, but in this case there exists the possibility that a printed source contains an explanation of "ninemen," especially considering how often it is specified that it's not "nine men." I'm asking to find out if it was ever stated anywhere, which may have included in-setting fluff, not simply designer intent. Apologies if you don't feel this is a sufficient distinction in this circumstance.

Comment: I've tweeted at him: https://twitter.com/modronGralamin/status/1334645653809496064

Comment: Nowhere does the question ask for designer intent. It asks for the definition/origin of a word. The designer may be--MAY be--uniquely positioned to speak to the origin of the word if it's one that he just made up. But designers would be very well positioned to answer most questions on this site--so that's a poor criteria for closing the question. We should ease back on the tendency toward hair-trigger closing of questions. We shouldn't close valid questions because we're afraid they may draw invalid answers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to Ed, he completely made it up out of whole cloth when he was 6, and later used it for the spell - From twitter:

> Nope. I made it up. ;}
> I'd penned a short story in which a wizard used a spell to fix the broken joints of 9 men after a battle; it became "ninemen" and (alliteration's artful aid) got hitched to the spell. I was 6 at the time, and D&D was still a decade away.

[Obligatory twitter link](https://twitter.com/TheEdVerse/status/1365349001508380673)

Comment: Well hot darn. Good to know... though I would still love to understand why the pronunciation changed - especially given that it got so *specific.* Resolves something that has been bugging me for a long time, though. Much obliged!

Comment: Ed replied to the tweet the next day saying, " I didn't want "nine-men," I wanted a 'new word' that sounded like a form of spell or magic ritual, so it could be used again for related magics."

Comment: Then that's what I'm gonna do.